# BAT скрипт на перезапуск процесса с проверкой условий

Tags: bat

Есть процесс Server.exe. Этот процесс автоматически запускает сторонние приложения (OPC серверы). Если Server.exe запущен - нужно завершить. Далее перезапустить процесс Server.exe если в списке запущенных процессов отсутствуют OPC-серверы (das.exe, aropc.exe, mpp.exe и modbusopcserver.exe). Если они не завершились, то принудительно завершить по истечению 20 секунд. Суть данной задачи в том, чтобы сервер запустился только тогда, когда остановились OPC-серверы.

Comment: Можно через WMI. Получаете экземпляры Win32_Process с заданными ExecutablePath, если нашлись - завершаете. Затем обычным порядком стартуете свой сервер. Не забудьте делать паузы - завершение выполняется не мгновенно. Используйте [WMI Code Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) или иное средство работы с WMI. PS. Лучше сразу пишите на VBS или PS, батник как-то не очень подходит для таких задач.